# Why does Keras.preprocessing.sequence pad_sequences process characters instead of words?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, speech-to-text, text-processing

I'm working on transcribing speech to text and ran into an issue (I think) when using `pad_sequences` in Keras. I pretrained a model which used `pad_sequences` on a dataframe and it fit the data into an array with the same number of columns & rows for each value. However when I used `pad_sequences` on transcribing text, the number of characters in that spoken string is how many rows are returned as a numpy array.

Say I have a string with 4 characters then it will return a `4 X 500` Numpy array. For a string with 6 characters it will return `6 X 500` Numpy array and so on.

My code for clarification:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import pandas as pd
from helperFunctions import *

jurors = ['Zack', 'Ben']
storage = []
storage_df = pd.DataFrame()


while len(storage) < len(jurors):
    print('Juror' + ' ' + jurors[len(storage)] + ' ' + 'is speaking:')
    init_rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio_data = init_rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio_data = init_rec.listen(source) #each juror speaks for 10 seconds
        audio_text = init_rec.recognize_google(audio_data)
        print('End of juror' + ' ' + jurors[len(storage)] + ' ' + 'speech')
        storage.append(audio_text)
        cleaned = clean_text(audio_text)
        tokenized = tokenize_text(cleaned)
        padded_text = padding(cleaned, tokenized) #fix padded text elongating rows
```

I use a helper function script:

```
def clean_text(text, stem=False):
    text_clean = '@\S+|https?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+'
    text = re.sub(text_clean, ' ', str(text).lower()).strip()
    #text = tf.strings.substr(text, 0, 300) #restrict text size to 300 chars
    return text

def tokenize_text(text):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
    return tokenizer

def padding(text, tokenizer):
    text = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text), 
                       maxlen = 500)
    return text
```

The text returned will be fed into a pre-trained model and I'm pretty sure that different length rows will cause an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tokenizer`'s methods such as `fit_on_texts` or `texts_to_sequences` expect a **list** of texts/strings as input (as their name suggests, i.e. `texts`). However, you are passing a single text/string to them and therefore it would iterate over its characters instead while assuming it's actually a list!

One way of resolving this is to add a check at the beginning of each function to make sure that the input data type is actually a list. For example:

```
def padding(text, tokenizer):
    if isinstanceof(text, str):
        text = [text]
    # the rest would not change...
```

You should also do this for the `tokenize_text` function. After this change, your custom functions would work on both a single string as well as a list of strings.

---

As an important side note, if the code you have put in your question belongs to the prediction phase there is a fundamental error in it: you should use the same `Tokenizer` instance you have used when training the model to ensure the mapping and tokenization is done the same way as in training phase. Actually, it does not make sense to create a new `Tokenizer` instance for each or all test samples (unless it has the same mapping and configuration as the one used in training phase).

Comment: Thank you! I actually read some documentation immediately after posting this that specified I wanted to save and reuse my tokenized weights. Your explanation made it much more clear though and the code worked!

Comment: hi @today I read your answer which is quite accurate, but I have another question in the same scenario, what if I have more than one Text column in the dataframe, how can we tokenize and pad_sequences those columns and reassign them to the Dataframe again. Here is my question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769093/after-tokenize-a-column-of-text-how-to-reassigned-that-tokenized-output-which